# Is this good practice to do in a function? calling a same function inside it's own function

Tags: javascript, function

```
function takaAnumber() {
  startHealth = parseInt(prompt("give a positive number "));
//here i am calling the same function inside the if()block if the input is not a number or lesser than 0 is this a good practice? 
  if (isNaN(startHealth) || startHealth <= 0) {
    takaAnumber();
  }
  // checkItsnumber();
  playerHealth = startHealth;
  monsterHealth = startHealth;
  adjustHealthBars(startHealth);
}
```

I am trying get a number as an input, by calling a function. Inside the function the I have wrote a if() statement to check its a number if isn't it will call the function again. My question is it safe(good practice) to call a function inside it's own function in a large project code.

Comment: It's called recursion. Your function will crash after around 200 times if you do that this way. I'm more concerned about using `prompt` which is very annoying for users

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach needs a return statement, because if the function returns, it goes on with the code of the calling function.

```
function takaAnumber() {
    const startHealth = parseInt(prompt("give a positive number ")); // declare variables
    if (isNaN(startHealth) || startHealth <= 0) {
        return takaAnumber();
    }
    // other code
}
```

Comment: But I'd say that still is not a good thing to do. if user input invalid values for thousands of time ( which quite unlikely but theoritically possible), your may got a STACKOVERFLOW. Better go with loop instead of recursion in this scenario.

Comment: that is right for this task. just to repeat with a `while` statement is shorter and better to understand.